# Excel 2016 Spreadsheet formulas and formats

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

What I am trying to do is set up an Excel sheet for my roommates and I to track our rent and bills split. I want to have it set up so I enter the name, date and value of the bill. Then I decide on how we split the cost and how much is owed or if it's owed per person. Then I want to enter how much each person paid to have it calculate how much each person owed. I cannot figure out what Excel formats, formulas, and conditions I need to use to set it up. I have seen an example of what  the formatting could look like in a Google Sheets page but it doesn't have all the functions I want. Any help on this is appreciated. Let me know if I need to put in any other information.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1500019/edit) to let us know what you have tried so far and how it fails to achieve the desired goal.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problem has been solved already. For example this App:
http://splid.app/english

There are also many alternatives if you don`t like this one.
https://alternativeto.net/software/splid/

You just need to enter your expense and the App will tell you who owes how much tho whom.